# Bash equivalent of which in R

Tags: r, equivalent

Is there a function in R to identify which library a package is installed in? (This is assuming that some packages are installed in a local directory, such as `~/R_libs`)

For example, in bash one can simply input `which [package name]` and it will return the location that the `[package name]` is executing from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want `find.package()`.

```
## path to package
find.package("base")
# [1] "/usr/lib/R/library/base"

## path to directory 
dirname(find.package("base"))
# [1] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Answer (score 4):

To find, for example, the path to package base (replace this with whichever package you want)

```
libs <- library()$results
libs[which (libs[,"Package"]=="base"), "LibPath"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method using `installed.packages`:

You can find the path to the package library with the following:

```
# return a matrix of p by 16 where p is the number of packages you have installed
packageInfo <- installed.packages()

# pull out the path of the library where data.table is installed, for example:
packageInfo["data.table", "LibPath"]
[1] "<path from root>/R/win-library/3.2"
```

As mentioned in the comments by @procrastinatus-maximus, it would be more compact to use
    `installed.packages()["data.table", "LibPath"]`

Calling `installed.packages()` causes R to hiccup (a super short delay), so if you are looking up multiple packages, or looking up further information about the packages, then saving the resulting matrix in a variable and pulling info from it directly has tended to be a little more pleasant in my experience.

Comment: why not just `installed.packages()["data.table", "LibPath"]`?